# I can't find Maven dependency for the code sample : Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(...);

Tags: spring, maven, security, jwt, key

I want to get the Maven depedency for this sample of code :

```
Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(signingKeySecret.getBytes());
```

Normally i should be in this depedency, but it seems to be absent :

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Anyone knows where is it located ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is part of `jjwt-impl`

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
    <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
    <version>0.11.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and forgot to remove  `<scope>runtime</scope>`  line from the dependency. It was resolved when I removed it.

**Below is my dependency:**

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
            <!-- <scope>runtime</scope> -->
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Can you [edit] this to emphasize the solution to the original problem, rather than the original problem you encountered? If your solution doesn’t also solve the original problem, then you should post a new question with your problem, and then answer it with what you discovered.

Comment: The recommendation you quote says not to use scope runtime: _"Specify [..] not as a runtime dependency but as a compile dependency."_, so exactly what is "odd"?

Comment: I do not see how this is an answer according to [answer]. In total it gives an impression of being a blog of what you did, learned and have problems with; implicitly asking for help. Seeing the "RESOLVED" in one of the previous versions more supports this impression than reduces it. If you cannot [edit] this into an obvious answer to the question at the top of the page (in contrast to a solution to only your problem) it probably is not an acceptable answer. Also, this is so indirecty and confusingly phrased that i really can't read through and get an impression of an actual answering attempt.

Comment: Hey everyone, I didn't mean to make my post seem like a blog post. I'm new collaborating in the platform and because I'm used to collaborating on slack with my peers I mistakenly did the same here, that's all. Sometimes things are simpler than we think. I recognize that I didn't pay attention to "Specify [..] not as a runtime dependency but as a compile dependency." portion of the other post. I do appreciate the feedback and will be more mindful in the future.

Comment: Good point. I got a runtimeOnly in y gradle file and changing it made it work.